# Amazon MWS API, listing seller's products that is updated after a specific date

Tags: report, amazon-mws

I am trying to list the products of a seller (using marketplaceID) that is created or updated after a specific date.

I tried RequestReport with ReportType `"_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_"` and setting StartDate to the target date but the data returned contains products that are created (or lastly updated) before that date.

https://developer.amazonservices.com/

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is not very specific on what 'StartDate' actually does:

> Start of a date range used for selecting the data to report.
>
> Type: xs:datetime
>
> Default: Now

If I recall correctly, this date does not relate to a products modification timestamps but to a products existance in the database. As an example, setting `StartDate` to yesterday should give you a list of products that were *in the database* within the last 24 hours. This includes products that were recently created and products that were created way before that but still exist.

I don't think it is possible to get a list of products that were *modified* within a timeframe (again, I'm writing this from my recollection on how this worked when I played with it)